# JS audioplayer not working - failed to load resource

Tags: javascript, audio-player

I'm creating a audio player on my webpage, the part of js is this:

```
    var songs = ["The Violence.mp3", "Welcome To The Breakdown.mp3", "Re-education.mp3"]

var songTitle = document.getElementById('songTitle');
var songSlider = document.getElementById('songSlider');
var currentTime = document.getElementById('currentTime');
var duration = document.getElementById('duration');
var volumeSlider = document.getElementById('volumeSlider');
var nextSongTitle = document.getElementById('nextSongTitle');

var song = new Audio();
var currentSong = 0;

window.onload = loadSong;

function loadSong () {
    song.src = "" + songs[currentSong];
    songTitle.textContent = (currentSong + 1) + ". " + songs[currentSong];
    nextSongTitle.innerHTML = "<b>Next Song: </b>" + songs[currentSong + 1 % songs.length];
    song.volume = volumeSlider.value;
    song.play();
    setTimeout(showDuration, 1000);
}
```

It doesn't work and it seems like it can't find the files, the console writes:

> GET file:///C:/Users/Kaja/Documents/%C5%A1kola/ZATLA/programov%C3%A1n%C3%AD/semestralka/The%20Violence.mp3 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

which I understand, but I am very sure the mp3 file is in here, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Feel free to delete this question since it is not useful to anyone but you.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, the problem was indeed in the name of the file (I'm just dumb and didn't notice that the name of the song was actually The Violence.mp3).